# Syntax error in azure devops build pipeline | Publishing wiki via rest api

Tags: azure-devops, build, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am stuck in the middle of a task in a build pipeline. My target is to - publish azure devops wiki from a code repository called `wiki` through a build pipeline task.
Here is the draft of the task

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
      inputs:
          azureSubscription: '$(service_connection)'
          ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
          Inline: |
            $url = 'https://dev.azure.com/test-platform/usecase_test/_apis/wiki/wikis?api-version=6.0'
            $body = 
             ------------------------------------
             -------------------------------
             ------------------------------

            
            $body = $body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
                  
            $uri_tag = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}
          azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

I got the publish/create wiki rest api from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/wikis/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#create-code-wiki . I don't know how to put values to $body variable. I want to add these following values to the $body. As I don't know the syntax well, it is returning me errors.

```
{
  "version": {
    "version": "main"
  },
  "type": "codeWiki",
  "name": "wiki",
  "projectId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "repositoryId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "mappedPath": "/"
}
```

Also is it the right way to publish wiki via a build pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your PowerShell sample to run the Rest API, you need to change the following points:

1.Since you are using `$(system.accessstoken)` for authentication, you need to convert the token to base64 and use Basic authentication type.

2.You can refer to the following body sample:

```
$body= @'
{
  "version": {
    "version": "master"
  },
  "type": "codeWiki",
  "name": "sampleCodeWiki1",
  "projectId": "aaea0fe6-801c-46e3-be1e-dcacdcb0c384",
  "repositoryId": "d7c2d91d-9175-4a45-97bc-aa743275bebc",
  "mappedPath": "/folder"
}

'@
```

Here is the PowerShell sample:

```
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/wiki/wikis?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$(system.accesstoken)"))

$body= @'
{
  "version": {
    "version": "master"
  },
  "type": "codeWiki",
  "name": "sampleCodeWiki2",
  "projectId": "aaea0fe6-801c-46e3-be1e-dcacdcb0c384",
  "repositoryId": "d7c2d91d-9175-4a45-97bc-aa743275bebc",
  "mappedPath": "/test"
}

'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $body-ContentType application/json 

echo $response
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked perfectly. Thank you for your time and effort

Comment: Could you please help me out with this following error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75068695/if-condition-in-azurepowershell-task-in-build-pipeline

Comment: @AlJubaiar Sure. Post answer in the new ticket. I have shared a work sample. Feel free to check it. :)