# IF condition in AzurePowershell task in build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I have an azure build pipeline task that publishes/creats wiki from a repository. The code is the following

```
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      inputs:
          azureSubscription: '$(service_connection)'
          ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
          Inline: |
            $url = 'https://dev.azure.com/data-platform/uc_test/_apis/wiki/wikis?api-version=6.0'
            
            $body= @'
            {
              "version": {
                "version": "main"
              },
              "type": "codeWiki",
              "name": "wiki",
              "projectId": "c800c392-67aa-4892-a070-7284435bda9b",
              "repositoryId": "2avd6061-b265-417f-8b55-81cc65kf90b6",
              "mappedPath": "/"
            }

            '@
            
            $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json 
            echo $response 


          azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

On the first run of this build pipeline, it successfully publishes/creates wiki. But in the next run, it throws the following error

```
 {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Wiki already exists with
     | name
     | 'wiki'.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Wiki.Server.WikiAlreadyExistsException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Wiki.Server","typeKey":"WikiAlreadyExistsException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

How can I tackle this issue? I was thinking if there any way to implement a if else condition under AzurePowerShell@5 task - if wiki doesn't exist- create wiki, else skip the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wiki already exists with

The cause of the issue is that wiki names are unique. When you run successfully for the first time, the wiki name already exists. You need to change the wiki name to let it work again.

> I was thinking if there any way to implement a if else condition under AzurePowerShell@5 task - if wiki doesn't exist- create wiki, else skip the script.

Yes. You can use PowerShell script to run the Rest API: [Wikis - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/wikis/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#query-in-project) to list all wiki names.  Then we can check if the wiki name exists and do next  actions.

Here is an example:

```
$Testwikiname = "sampleCodeWiki10"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname/_apis/wiki/wikis?api-version=7.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$(system.accesstoken)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json 

echo $response 

$count = 0

Foreach($wikiname in $response.value.name)
{
  echo $wikiname 

  if($wikiname -eq $Testwikiname)
  {
     $count = $count + 1 
  }
}

echo $count

if($count -eq 1 )
{
  echo "Wiki Page: $Testwikiname exists in the project"
}

else
{

$url1="https://dev.azure.com/orgname/project/_apis/wiki/wikis?api-version=6.0"


$JSON = 
"{
  `"version`": {
    `"version`": `"master`"
  },
  `"type`": `"codeWiki`",
  `"name`": `"$Testwikiname`",
  `"projectId`": `"aaea0fe6-801c-46e3-be1e-dcacdcb0c384`",
  `"repositoryId`": `"d7c2d91d-9175-4a45-97bc-aa743275bebc`",
  `"mappedPath`": `"/test5`"

}"
   

$response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json 

echo " Wiki Page: $Testwikiname  has been created"


  
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Worked this time too! Thanks Kevin. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your task works as expected.... Before creation, you have to check the existence of your wiki... Check this request: [Query by name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/wikis/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#query-by-name)